# Check whether text field contains numbers only and has to be 11 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this function to check whether the text field contains numbers only, if there are letters in this field then an error should show

```
//Tel Validate
function is_valid_tel() {
 $this = $("#inputTel");
 var pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]*$");
if(pattern.test($this.val())){ // valid
 if ($this.closest(".control-group").hasClass("error"))
  $this.closest(".control-group").removeClass("error");
  $this.siblings(".help-inline").css("display", "none");
return true;
} else { // error
 if (!$this.closest(".control-group").hasClass("error"))
  $this.closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
  $this.siblings(".help-inline").css("display", "block");
  return false;
 }
}
```

When i enter letters into the text field i get no error thrown. My jquery/javascript is limited but I thought this would at least work? as the reg exp checks for numbers between 0-9. I would also like to check that if a number is entered then it matches 11 digits

Any help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this regular expression `^\d{11}$`

**old regex**

`^` begin of string

`[0-9]*` 0 or more digits

`$` end of string

**new regex**

`^` begin of string

`\d{11}` 11 digits (`\d` == `[0-9]`)

`$` end of string

Comment: thanks for expanding upon that answer, though still not working, maybe an issue elsewhere? though all my other functions work apart form this one.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following RegExp

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]{11}$");
```

Which is a more readable version of :

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^\d{11}$");
```

You will find a handy reference about special characters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions).